# How to get GPS location data from Corona SDK when device is not moving

Tags: lua, gps, location, coronasdk

I have run the Corona SDK sample GPS app on an iPhone 5s and seen that the location event is not fired. Is this simply because the device needs to move beyond the configured threshold distance or is there a method to get the location data as a basic function call?

The code which the sample suggests should provide geo-location data is this:

```
Runtime:addEventListener( "location", function(e)
    local lat = e.latitude
    local lon = e.longitude

    print(lat..","..lon)
end )
```

However the print statement never fires, as witnessed in the console. What should be done to have this work other than enabling location services for the app? Is there a direct request to retrieve the current location in the API?

I have an answer to the problem. Want to share.

Comment: I just want to make sure your doing it correctly.  Are you loading it on your iPhone then watching the terminal output via the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a new requirement by Apple in the plist. A value must be specified for the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key.